# $3n = 8x+4$ control flag inside of a function

Tags: functions, integers, natural-numbers

I want to be able to evaluate wether the result of a function satisfies an expression. Is this possible to do?

**Example**

I have an expression, a linear polynomial:
$$8x+4$$ for $x\in\mathbb{N}$

If I have, say a function:
$$f(n)=\frac{3n}{2(-1)^k}$$
also $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

then when $n=4$ the numerator returns $12$ and the above expression is satisfied if $x=1$ for the numerator. $x$ can be any natural number for other results of course. Don't know if that made sense.

I need some variable to return true ($1$) or false ($0$) or $-1$ or $1$ to control some value when $8x+4 = 3n$.
So that I can control some other function.

In other words when $3n$ does not result in the values of the sequence $\{4,12,20,28,36,...\}$ produced by $8x+4$, it returns $-1$ or otherwise $1$. I have used a variable $k$ for this. But how can I manipulate this function so that values in the first expression acts like an on/off switch? I don't want to use modulus.

Comment: I'm confused-- when $8x+4=3n$ return $1$ else return $0$ [Then you say to return $1$ or $-1.$ -- seeming conflict.] Either way your function is of two variables $x,n.$ Another thing, looks to me like $f(4)=12/2=6,$ rather than $12.$

Comment: I messed it up somehow when I wrote it. It should be the numerator. I've corrected it now.